# Hide Thumbnail div when there's not image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I wanna hide a div class="thumbnail" when there's not an image, 'cause if not, it looks so: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCy4f.jpg)

[image]

The html code that I've:

```
<div class="thumbnail" >
    <img id="bild" src="#" /></div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files); angular.element(this).scope().readURL(this.files);"/>
</span>
```

and the js:

```
$scope.readURL = function(files) { //This' to show the image
    if (files && files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#bild').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
};
```

As you can see `readURL()` shows the image and then it is ok, but before it doesn't look good. I'm using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `hide` the `div thumbnail` and after upload the file `display` the `div`.

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#bild').attr('src', e.target.result); 
            $('.thumbnail').css('display','block');  
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }

}

$("#imginput").change(function () {
    readURL(this);

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5y1fht8c/)

Answer (score 1):

The first, remove property `src="#"` in your `<img />` tag.

`<img id="bild" />`

The second, add property `src` to your `<img />` whenever you need (not always).

```
<script>
$('#bild').prop('src', e.target.result)
</script>
```

The third, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` (jQuery version >= 1.6)

Comment: It was ok, but there was still some line. But Many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `error()` method on an `img` to discover when it fails to load. From there you can just `hide()` the element:

```
$('#bild').error(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

You would need to also `show()` the `img` within the `reader.onload` handler too:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#bild').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
};
```

Comment: I notice you say `or .remove()`. It must be a problem. Because if you `remove` an element, so you **cannot** call that element again.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ng-hide attribute as you are already using AngularJS. By below code you can get `<img>` element:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#bild'))
```

After that you can pass src attribute in ng-hide condition and check for non-# value:

```
<div class="thumbnail" ng-hide="angular.element(document.querySelector('#bild')).attr('src')=='#'" >
    <img id="bild" src="#" /></div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files); angular.element(this).scope().readURL(this.files);"/>
</span>
```

This way you will be able to achieve your task using AngularJS,
Happy Coding!